# Problem using ggplot 2 in R to display country data vs gdp

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I am working with the library gapminder as follows:

```
library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)
db1 <-gapminder
db1Asia<-db1 %>% filter(year==1962 | year==1967) %>% filter(country=="China" | country=="India")
ggplot(data=db1Asia %>% filter(year==1962), aes(x=country, y=pop, color=country)) +geom_bar()
```

to study the evolution of the population of the two nations between 1962 and 1967. However, I get the following error:

```
Error in `f()`:
! stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic.
```

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-barplots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization) and I cannot see what I am doing wrong. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Try: `geom_col`?

Answer (score 0):

Quinten's comment works

```
library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)
db1 <-gapminder
db1Asia<-db1 %>% filter(year==1962 | year==1967) %>% filter(country=="China" | country=="India")
ggplot(data=db1Asia %>% filter(year==1962), aes(x=country, y=pop, color=country)) +geom_col()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add geom_bar(stat = 'identity'):

```
    library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)
db1 <-gapminder
db1Asia<-db1 %>% filter(year==1962 | year==1967) %>% filter(country=="China" | country=="India")
ggplot(data=db1Asia %>% filter(year==1962), aes(x=country, y=pop, color=country)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

Comment: That is indeed an option. It is the same as using `geom_col`.